# Linear Programming: Three variable graphical solution

Tags: optimization, graphing-functions, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

> A small bank offers three type of loans: housing loans at $8.50$%
>   interest, education loans at $13.75$% interest rates, and loans to
>   senior citizens at $12.25$% interest. Further, it needs to adhere to
>   certain policy restrictions. The restrictions require the bank to
>   ensure that Condition 1: housing loans make up between $25$% and $60$% of
>   the total loan amount disbursed;and Condition 2: the amount of loans
>   disbursed to senior citizens should be least one third of  the total
>   amount disbursed as loans. In a particular year, its lending capacity
>   is $25,000,000\$$. The bank would like to disburse loans so as to
>   maximize its earnings from the interest paid. Solve the problem
>   graphically by taking two at a time.

From the problem, I derive the following LP model:

**Decision variables:**

$X_1:$ Amount disbursed as housing loan.
$X_2:$ Amount disbursed as education loan.
$X_3:$ Amount disbursed as loans to senior citizens.

Maximize $$0.085X_1 + 0.1375X_2 + 0.1225X_3$$

Subject to constraints:

$$X_1 \ge 625 \times 10^4$$
$$X_1 \le 150 \times 10^5$$
$$X_3 \ge \frac{25}{3} \times 10^6$$
where $X_1,X_2,X_3 \ge 0$

My question is: Is this formulation correct? and how to solve this three variable equations using graphical method. Precisely I don't understand "Solve the problem
 graphically by taking two at a time"

Answer (score 1):

It looks sensible, except I think your constraints should be
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_1&\geq0.25(X_1+X_2+X_3) \\
X_1&\leq0.6(X_1+X_2+X_3) \\
X_3&\geq\frac{1}{3}(X_1+X_2+X_3) \\
X_1+X_2+X_3&\leq25000000 \\
X_1,X_2,X_3&\geq0
\end{aligned}
$$
Of course, at the optimal solution, the bank will lend all it can, but that is for the optimisation to take care of.

Comment: Hm, then we need  another constraint: $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 <= 25,000,000\$$

Comment: @Quixotic: Yes of course, I'll edit!